# Delayed jobs and display results in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, delayed-job

I would like to use delayed_job gem to process long queries for notification, such as: counting number of new emails, updating new members, similar to Facebook's new email notification.

I followed Ryan's railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised). But how should I go about showing notifications once the queries completed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In background job, store its results in the database. Then later, when user logs in, show those notifications (and delete them from the database).

(*I am assuming here that you're talking about notifications in a web app, not emails*).

Comment: Hi Sergio, thanks for the suggestion. I also have a search box that returns completely different types of data, and thus presented in multiple tabs. I would like to query for the active tab first, then run in the background for other tabs. When queries are done, display a notification on the tabs. How should I refresh page to get these notification displayed?

Comment: It's up to you, mate. Use jquery/ajax, for example :)